# Is there a Cassandra (CQL) package for Dart?

Tags: cassandra, dart, cql

Is there a Cassandra package for Dart?

I looked in the official Dart package web site and googled a lot but cannot find any mention.

Looking at the equivalent [Cassandra Go package](https://github.com/tux21b/gocql) it seems not too difficult to code it but I'm avoiding reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there isn't. There are actually not many server-side focused libraries abound, especially databases. There is an SQL library for various SQL databases, and I think Mongo. But not much else. You will probably have to port over the library or design a new one from scratch.

At least to my knowledge, there isn't a Cassandra library. If you don't get around to it, I might give it a shot if I ever find time.